# How do I gain access to a custom UITableViewCell from textFieldDidEndEditing?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I have a custom `UITableViewCell` where I've added a `UITextField`, I'd like to perform some validation on the textfield and set a `hasError` property on the cell to maybe add a error label to the cell and change the textfield back color.

I'm not using a storyboard and creating my custom cell / `UITableViewCell` programatically.

I'm using `textFieldDidEndEditing` in my `UIViewController` to detect text changes and have no access to the cell, to set my `hasError` property.

I guess I could loop around the views / textfields by a tag to field the textfield then gain it's parent.

Or maybe I should implement my own version of `textFieldDidEndEditing` which then fires another event which has the cell and the textfield as parameters.

But I'm not sure if that's the best approach or how to fire an event.

Comment: if you are adding `textField` in custom cell, then why don't you implement `textFieldDidEndEditing` inside custom cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Protocol`.  https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Protocol.html

A simple example:

**cellForRow**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = ....
    cell.delegate = self
    return cell
}
```

**Your `UITableViewCell` subclass:**

```
class Cell: UITableViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate {

    // MARK: - Properties

    weak var delegate: CellDelegate?
    ....

    // MARK: - Functions

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        self.delegate?.cell(self, textFieldDidEndDiting: textField)
    }
}
```

**Your Protocol**

```
protocol CellDelegate: class {
    func cell(_ cell: Cell, textFieldDidEndDiting textField: UITextField)
}
```

Then finally, conform your controller to that protocol like so:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, CellDelegate {

    func cell(_ cell: Cell, textFieldDidEndDiting textField: UITextField) {

    }

}
```

Comment: still not called in viewController